# Conflict when both infinispan and qpid-broker registers URLStreamHandlers

Tags: java, infinispan, qpid

I'm trying to upgrade `infinispan` from version 9 to 13 in our application. Since version 12.1, infinispan has a [`ClasspathURLStreamHandler`](https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/12.1/apidocs/org/infinispan/commons/util/ClasspathURLStreamHandler.html) that automatically registers itself (on Java >= 9).

This causes issues as our application also uses `qpid-broker`, and that library also has a [`URLStreamHandler`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.qpid/qpid-broker-core/latest/org/apache/qpid/server/util/urlstreamhandler/classpath/Handler.html) that automatically registers itself.

Now, I don't fully understand how `URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory` works - but my understanding of the problem is:

1. Both infinispan and qpid-broker tries to register their respective URLStreamHandler, for the `classpath` protocol
2. Only one URLStreamHandler can be registered. In this case infinispan happens to be first, and its handler is registered.
3. When starting up qpid-broker, it tries to read `system.properties` using an URL `classpath:system.properties` (this happens in `org.apache.qpid.server.SystemLauncher`).
4. There is no `system.properties` on the classpath (I think) - and infinispan's handler returns null, resulting in a `NullPointerException` in qpid-broker.

Note that the behavior of infinispan's handler is different compared to the behaviour of qpid-broker's handler, which throws an exception on failure (e.g. `FileNotFoundException` or `MalformedURLException`) instead of returning null.

Questions:

- How is the fact that libraries can (and apparently will) register things like `URLStreamHandlerFactory`, which affects the JVM globally and can only be registered *once*, usually handled in large applications like ours that can have lots of dependencies?
- Could this problem be considered a bug in infinispan? If its handler would have the same behaviour as qpid-broker's, i.e. throw an exception instead of returning null, maybe it wouldn't have matter which handler is actually registered and used?
- Is there some other way, beside adjusting the behaviour of infinispan's handler, to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the behaviour is wrong. I've created an issue https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-14732 and it will be incorporated in 14.0.8.Final.